# Sliding menu works fine but does double animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have just succeeded to make a menu that comes sliding in from the top with the help of Jquery. When I press the tab 'menu' it comes in/down and when I leave the menu, it slides back.
The problem is that when I press the menu tab quickly 2 times, it goes down the double amount of pixels.
Also when I leave the menu it goes up, but when I while the animation is still happening go back in and leave again, it also goes up the double amount of pixels.

This is my code:
CSS

```
#menu {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:-203px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:1;
}
#menucontentwrapper {
    background-color: #330066;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    border-left: 3px solid #000000;
    border-right: 3px solid #000000;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #000000;
}
#menucontent {
    height: 200px;
    width: 820px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#menutabwrapper {
    width: 820px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#menutab {
    background-color: #330066;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100px;
    float: right;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
    border-left: 3px solid #000000;
    border-right: 3px solid #000000;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #000000;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

The body

```
<div id="menu">
    <div id="menucontentwrapper">
        <div id="menucontent"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="menutabwrapper">
        <div id="menutab">MENU</div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
$('#menutab').click(function() {
$('#menu').animate({
top: '+=203',
}, 1000, function() {
// Animation complete.
});
})
$('#menucontentwrapper').mouseleave(function() {
    $('#menu').animate({
        top: '-=203',
    }, 500, function() {
// Animation complete.
    });
})
</script>
```

Do any of you know a solution to this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this way:

```
var $menutab = $('#menutab');
var $menu = $('#menu');
$menutab.one('click', slideDown);//Initially register one click event to slideDown

function slideDown()
{
     $menu.animate({
        top: '+=203',
    }, 1000, function () {
        $('#menucontentwrapper').one('mouseleave', slideUp);// On completion of animation register one mouseleave event to slideUp
    });

}
function slideUp()
{
    $menu.animate({
        top: '-=203',
    }, 1000, function () {
        $menutab.one('click', slideDown);// On completion of animation register one click event to slideDown
    });

}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QRU4H/show/)**

The method works because by using `one` instead of `on` to attach the event handler, it makes it so neither event is handled while the animation is running.  This is because a handler attached by `one` only executes once and is then removed.  After the animation is complete the appropriate handler is attached in the complete callback of the animate function.

See **[.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/)**

Comment: No problem.  I never knew about `one`.  Btw, I know its an odd use case, but if you were to bind multiple events, like `one('mouseover click')`, it becomes glitchy.  http://jsfiddle.net/QRU4H/3/

Answer (score 2):

Check out jQuery [stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) method.

Before you call your `animate` functions, call `stop`.  Using the parameters true, true will cause all of #menu's running animation to jump to the end.  On the off chance you'll have multiple animations intentionally running, then you should check out how to use the queue parameter.

```
$('#menutab').click(function() {
    $('#menu').stop(true, true).animate({
        top: '0px',
    }, 1000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
    });
})
$('#menucontentwrapper').mouseleave(function() {
    $('#menu').stop(true, true).animate({
        top: '-203px',
    }, 500, function() {
// Animation complete.
    });
})
```

Comment: +1 for adding expl... :) Thanks. By the way stop will not still work here because of top +=203/-=203 which will go on from the current top value which is under animation.

Comment: Thanks @PSL I changed from relative to absolute so that it at least works.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to run a check to see if the element is in the middle of an animation on your click function:

```
$('#menutab').click(function() {
    if( !$('#menu').is(':animated') ) {
        $('#menu').animate({
            top: '+=203',
        }, 1000, function() {
        // Animation complete.
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: I think the problem would persist if you click twice